# python: read txt file into pandas where the data is separated by a randon number of spaces

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I have to load a txt file into pandas that look like this:

```
20221001T000022649  sdff002     0011   $LNKD       word1 word2 word3
20221001T000022733  SDSD002     0011     SD8      word1 word2 word3 word4
20221001T000022758     SDSD002   0011     NLP     word1 word2 word3 word1word2 word3
20221001T000022808  SDSD002   0011     JKT   word1 word2 word3 word1 word2 
20221001T000022823      SDSD002   0011   SD8     word1 word2 word3
```

I was thinking about:

```
mydf = pd.read_csv("test_query.txt", sep = "   ")
```

Assuming that the words are separated by one space and the other records are separated by more than one space.
the last words word1 word2 etc should all together go in one column.
This does not work because gives several empty columns since the spaces are random.

What is for sure is that there is no space in the first 4 records i.e.  20221001T000022649  sdff002     0011   $LNKD

[image]

So how would you go about this problem?
Parsing one line by line?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd make sure you use the pd.read_csv function for reading csv files. So what you could do is either write a program that transforms you .txt file into a csv and then run it again or start from csv.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

```
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> rows = []
>>> for line in data.split("\n"):
>>>     chunks = re.split(' +', line)
>>>     rows.append(chunks[:4] + [','.join(chunks[4:])])
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
>>>
>>> print(df)
                    0        1     2      3                                   4
0  20221001T000022649  sdff002  0011  $LNKD                   word1,word2,word3
1  20221001T000022733  SDSD002  0011    SD8             word1,word2,word3,word4
2  20221001T000022758  SDSD002  0011    NLP  word1,word2,word3,word1word2,word3
3  20221001T000022808  SDSD002  0011    JKT      word1,word2,word3,word1,word2,
4  20221001T000022823  SDSD002  0011    SD8                   word1,word2,word3
```

Comment: It seems that this does not work since the collection of words at the end should go in one single column and the number of words is random

Comment: Ah ok.. That being the case I'd do what Lario Sedic said.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show and example of how you could clean up the data before constructing the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex as seperator

```
pd.read_csv("test_query.txt", sep = '\s+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use `engine='python'` to force using at least 2 spaces as separator (`sep='\s{2,}'`):

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_query.txt", sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', header=None)
```

Output:

```
                    0        1   2      3                                   4
0  20221001T000022649  sdff002  11  $LNKD                   word1 word2 word3
1  20221001T000022733  SDSD002  11    SD8             word1 word2 word3 word4
2  20221001T000022758  SDSD002  11    NLP  word1 word2 word3 word1word2 word3
3  20221001T000022808  SDSD002  11    JKT       word1 word2 word3 word1 word2
4  20221001T000022823  SDSD002  11    SD8                   word1 word2 word3
```